# Laravel arrays and foreach

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach

So I'm sending from Ionic app to API via POST request an array of condiments which are on mobile part represented as checkboxes. I want to get the checkboxes which are checked so I can create table rows accordingly.

The method that is called upon route triggering has this part:

```
$condiments = Input::only('condiments');

foreach ($condiments as $condiment) {
        if ($condiment['checked'] == 1) {
            OrderCondiment::create(['order_item_id' => $orderItem, 
                                    'condiment_id' => $condiment->id]);
        }
}
```

But I get `Illegal string offset 'checked'` error. I tried with `$condiment->checked` but then I get `Trying to get the property of non-object` error...what am I missing...besides coffee

**EDIT**

```
dd($condiments)

array:1 [
  "condiments" => "[{"id":1,"name":"ut","price":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":1},{"id":2,"name":"ipsam","price":5,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":1},{"id":3,"name":"dolores","price":10,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":1},{"id":4,"name":"esse","price":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":5,"name":"aliquid","price":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":6,"name":"sunt","price":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":7,"name":"saepe","price":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":8,"name":"impedit","price":10,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":9,"name":"dolores","price":4,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0},{"id":10,"name":"veniam","price":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"checked":0}]"
]
```

Comment: What does `dd('$condiments)` show?

Comment: Anything from `Input` is an array; you cannot do this `$condiment->id` it should be: `$condiment['id']`

Comment: Yes, but it is erroring on the row where "if" clause is

Comment: Ok, well, @AlexeyMezenin  is right in that you should be using `dd` to do some debugging.

Comment: I did provide the output, didn't I? :) If I knew how to debug it myself, i wouldn't ask

Comment: hm, you did. But I guess I expect people to try and work things out on their own and not use StackOverflow as a "support forum", since this isn't really a Q&A thing - then again i don't run SO so it's not my call

Comment: Dude...I am trying to work it out for the last 2hrs, I didn't come here after 5mins of being stuck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert string to array

```
$condiments = Input::only('condiments');
$condiments= json_decode( $condiments['condiments']) ;
foreach ($condiments as $condiment) {
    if ($condiment->checked == 1) {
        OrderCondiment::create(['order_item_id' => $orderItem, 
                                'condiment_id' => $condiment->id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array -> error on line 32 (where "if" clause is)

Comment: use $condiment->checked  instead $condiment['checked']